# Is there a way to determine fragmentation statistics about a single file on Win2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, fragmentation

Basically, I don't care about fragmentation on the disk as a whole, I'm just curious about one file in particular...  in my case, a SQL database and transaction log file.  I'm looking for something that will provide very basic statistics - number of fragments, average fragement size, etc.  I'm NOT looking for fragmentation statistics of the SQL data / indexes - I already know how to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - contig.exe can do this (you want the -a flag)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx

Comment: +1 - Good utility, that.

Comment: This month's TechNet mag discusses this utility.